# Icon shows rectangle block when using react native vector icons with react native web nextjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web, next.js, react-native-web

I'm trying to use React Native Vector Icons in my Next.js app, but the icons are not displaying. I followed the steps in the documentation, but the icons just show up as blank spaces. Here's what

I've done so far:
Installed the react-native-vector-icons package using npm.
Imported the Icon component from the package and used it in my React component.
Added the necessary font files to my Next.js project and loaded them in my _document.js file.
Verified that the font family name used by the Icon component matches the font family name in the font file.
Despite all this, the icons still won't display. What could be causing this issue? Are there any additional steps I need to take to get the icons to show up? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add all the relevant code please - see [ask], [mcve]